# Call C++ inRange function in OpenCV 2.3

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV 2.1, I applied color filtering on cv::Mat with cv::inRange in this way:

```
cv::CvScalar* scalar_low = new cv::CvScalar(10,20,30,0);
cv::CvScalar* scalar_up = new cv::CvScalar(20,30,40,0)
cv::Mat* in = new cv::Mat(cv::Size(10,10), CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat* out = new cv::Mat(cv::Size(10,10), CV_8UC1);

cv::inRange(*in, *scalar_low, *scalar_up, *out); // <-----
```

In OpenCV 2.3 (current), cv::inRange with cv::CvScalar as parameter is no longer supported.

```
void inRange(Mat src, Mat lowerb, Mat upperb, Mat dst);
```

How can I use this function in C++ with the current definition?

Comment: current version of OpenCV is 2.4.1!

Answer (score 3):

Present Version of OpenCV is 2.4.1.

Please read the documents in this version : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange

Below is the current format :

`C++: void inRange(InputArray src, InputArray lowerb, InputArray upperb, OutputArray dst)`

And if you want to see a correct definition of it, check out line 122 of [camshiftdemo.cpp](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp) that comes with opencv samples.

```
inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, smin, MIN(_vmin,_vmax)),Scalar(180, 256, MAX(_vmin, _vmax)), mask);
```

Hope you can figure out the correct definition from it.

Answer (score 0):

below works for me with opencv 2.4.1:

```
cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(159, 135, 135), cv::Scalar(179, 255, 255), dstB);
```